# A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am just new to CodeIgniter and i encounter a PHP error -

> Severity: Notice  Message: Undefined variable

My Controller :  `C:\wamp\www\Code1\application\config\hello.php`

```
<?php
class Hello extends Controller {

    var $name;
    var $color;

    function Hello()
    {
        parent::Controller();       
        $this->name = 'Andi';
        $this->color= 'red';
    }

    function you()
    {
        $data['name'] = $this->name;
        $data['color'] = $this->color;
        $this->load->view('you_view', $data);
    }
}
?>
```

My Views :  `C:\wamp\www\Code1\application\views\you_view.php`

```
Hello, 
<font color="<?=$color?>"><?=$name?></font>!
```

Comment: Which variable says it is undefined?

Comment: Variables undefined are colors and name @devon

Comment: Off topic but you have extends Controller I think it should be CI_Controller and `function __construct() { parent::__construct();}`

Answer (score 1):

first:
the construct function in php is not the same name of it's classname.
so change your construct function like this:

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();       
    $this->name = 'Andi';
    $this->color= 'red';
}
```

then ,For ease of understanding,please put your controller file under application/controllers files!

Comment: I encounter another eror following your advise @smallerpig                    A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Class 'Controller' not found

Filename: controllers/hello.php

Line Number: 2

Backtrace:

Comment: please put your hello.php under application/controllers files and change the filename to Hello.php. and change the parent class to CI_Controller

Comment: Is my pleasure to help you!@ManuelSebastianSanchez